# Python-map: builtins.KeyError in line 568 of nmap.py

Tags: python, nmap

I am wanting to have a script which scans my local network for anybody who has opened an SSH login. I have a script which randomly generates a local IP and sees if the IP is "up". However, I keep getting a dictionary "builtins.KeyError" no matter how I change and fiddle with my code. This error only arises when I use my ipGenerator which returns an ip address as a string. If I manually enter in the IP address into the variable `ip` it runs fine. I am using WingIDE and I have even stopped the code at the offending line and manually entered the `ip` variable which was generated and the code ran fine. Yet whenever the variable is referencing the random IP generator function, the code fails with `builtins.KeyError: [generated ip address]`. The line of code which fails is `port22 = nm[ip]['tcp'][22]['state']`. Here is the code thus far:

```
import nmap
from generate_ip import ipPick

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

ip = ipPick()
nm.scan(ip, '22')
port22 = nm[ip]['tcp'][22]['state']
```

Interestingly enough the line `nm.scan(ip, '22')` works completely find. But it seems to fail when the dictionary entry is accessed by the problem line of code. Any ideas as to why it fails with the function and not with the manual entry?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `nm` -- a `PortScanner` object -- as a dictionary.

```
>>> type(nm)
<class 'nmap.nmap.PortScanner'>
```

Use this instead:

```
>>> scanned=nm.scan(ip, '22')
>>> scanned.keys() # list keys
dict_keys(['nmap', 'scan'])
>>> scanned['scan'][ip]['tcp'][22]['state']
'closed'
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Needed to put the dictionary somewhere.